# How to insert data from DataSnapshot to LiveData<List<Model>>?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-livedata, lifecycle

I need to insert the data I got from firebase to a LiveData<List>, I'm not sure how to do so

```java
public LiveData<List<MedicationViewModel>> getAllMeds(){

        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
             LiveData<List<MedicationViewModel>> medics; //Return this 
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                            MedicationViewModel medic = ds.getValue(MedicationViewModel.class);
                            Log.d("TAG", medic.getMedName());
                             //TODO
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: Here's a helpful resource that talks about this very thing in detail.https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html

Comment: I am having trouble understanding you code. What id `MedicationViewModel` so that I would know to help. because , you can't have a list of and object which inherits from the `ViewModel` or `AndroidViewModel`. it does not work like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should divide your problem into steps:

1. Return the livedata: If you want to have a livedata it means you want someone to observe it, so I would suggest just having a livedata and return it to whoever wants to observe like so

   ```
   //=======Observer Activity/Fragment=============:
   final Observer<List<MedicationViewModel>> medsObserver = new Observer<List<MedicationViewModel>>() {
       @Override
       public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<MedicationViewModel> medsList) {
           // Do what you need when the new list arrives
       }
   };
   yourObject.getAllMeds().observe(context, medsObserver) //setting the observer
   //===============Your class============
   private final MutableLiveData<List<MedicationViewModel>> allMedsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
   //...
   public LiveData<List<MedicationViewModel>> getAllMeds(){
      return allMedsLiveData; //returning the liveData
   }
   ```
2. Fill the data when it comes from firebase:

   ```
   //===============Your class============
   private final MutableLiveData<List<MedicationViewModel>> allMedsLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>(); //the same one as the step 1
   private final List<MedicationViewModel> allMedsList = new ArrayList<>();
   //...
   private void setUpListener() {
      mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                       MedicationViewModel medic = ds.getValue(MedicationViewModel.class);
                       Log.d("TAG", medic.getMedName());
                       allMedsList.add(medic); // or update if exists (just adding to keep things simple, but you get the idea)
                   }
                   allMedsLiveData.postValue(allMedsList) //Using postvalue here in case the DB is fetching data on a worker thread, as it should. This call will launch the "medsObserver" observer on the observer activity/fragment on step 1

               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

               }
           });
    }
   ```

Hope it works for you!